# PHP Composer: "Package paypal/paypalhttp is abandoned"

Tags: php, paypal-rest-sdk

I have been using the PHP SDK, while doing some other composer stuff, we noticed this warning about the http portion of the sdk. `Package paypal/paypalhttp is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.`

I've tried deleting the paypalhttp directory and rerunning  composer update but it's a required dependency of `"paypal/paypal-checkout-sdk": "1.0.1"` which as far as I can tell is the current latest version of the SDK, at least as far as PayPal's own documentation is concerned (although I've learned by now not to always trust their docs). As such it reinstalled itself on a `composer update`.

Am I just supposed to ignore this? Am I using some old version of the sdk that relies on this abandoned package? Is there a newer alternative to either the SDK or the http package?

Comment: Contact Paypal. Apparently their newest SDK depends on the old abandoned one. You can ignore it, though, because the old SDK does still work, but I don't know for how long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the correct, newest checkout SDK for PHP. [Update: the PayPal-Checkout-PHP has been deprecated now as well...]